# Another Animal Guessing Riddle--What animal am I?

Tags: riddle, animals

Splendor, beauty, and rainbows of color,
Mythical, legend'ry, and glorious splendor,
Some of the many descriptions I have,

Lahwran a ot ytiralumis a sah daeherof ym,
Eulc a rof em esrever!

People say that a human went about faking me,
I say that that's a false statement.

Every young child wants t' meet me,
Every young child has me as a fantasy!

What mythical beast am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a

> unicorn

as

> It has colourful rainbow, ksut a sah, and everyone (at least childen) want to see it.

Comment: Yup. I shouldn't have added the reverse part because that gave it away.